# How to remove this brown color tag in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-formatting

I've added the 'Highlight Matching Tag' extension in VSCode which gives the underline(very faint) [you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDNVz.png) I suppose this brownish color tag highlight is in-built (I went through other extensions I have, and none confer this property). How can I disable this? New to coding and VSCode, feel free to dumb your answers down for me, I would appreciate it. [My list of extensions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgBmv.png)

Comment: that is the default VSC `Highlight Matching Tag` functionality

Comment: There is another extension that goes by the same name, on disabling that and restarting VSCode, the highlight remains. How do I edit this color?

Comment: look in the list of theme colors what the name is of the color and customize it in your `settings.json` for your theme, (many examples here on SO)